# Observer on NSNotificationCenter that can handle multiple notifications

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotifications

I have an observer lets call it `Subscriber` and I want to have it registered on `NSNotificationCenter` like so:

```
NSNotificationCenter *notificationCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[notificationCenter addObserver:self
                    selector:@selector(post:)
                    name:nil
                    object:nil];
```

Where `post:` is:

```
- (void)post:(NSNotification *)notification {
    if (notification == nil) {
        // Throw an exception
    }
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:nil object:nil];
}
```

I would like to extend `Subscriber` and create classes like `PictureSubscriber` and then post notifications to the `PictureSubscriber` and have it handle multiple types of notifications like so:

**PictureViewController**

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultInstance] postNotification:@"UpdatePictureNotification" object:self userInfo:urlDict];

...

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultInstance] postNotification:@"DeletePictureNotification" object:self userInfo:urlDict];
```

Then ideally what I would like is for `PictureSubscriber` to be able to receive different types of `NSNotification`s. How would I accomplish this?

Comment: You can just create one observer key only and use the userInfo as a dictionary or custom object that includes whether it was a UpdatePictureNotification or DeletePictureNotification.

Comment: Can you give me an example? I am coming from a Java background.

Comment: Just take a look at Apples Guide for registering Key-Value-Observing. I hope it is the functionality you are looking for.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOBasics.html

Comment: I ended up creating my own "Event Bus", thanks for link though its something I could have looked up myself anyways.

Comment: This is a serious misuse of `NSNotificationCenter`. Apple has extensive documentation on using it correctly. There's generally no reason to reinvent it. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Introduction/introNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000043i It is very important to learn the Cocoa patterns to build iOS apps. Trying to apply Java patterns to Cocoa will lead to really convoluted software. Many ideas don't translate directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

//create contstant strings

```
#define kUpdatePictureNotification @"UpdatePictureNotification"
#define kDeletePictureNotification @"DeletePictureNotification"
#define kReasonForNotification @"ReasonForNotification"
#define kPictureNotification @"PictureNotification"
```

// to post a notfication call this method and give the reason either kUpdatePictureNotification or kDeletePictureNotification

```
-(void)postNotificationGivenReason:(NSString *)reason
{
    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          reason, kReasonForNotification,
                            // if you need more stuff add more
                          nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kPictureNotification object:nil userInfo:dict];

}
```

// Here is the observer:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(pictureNotification:) name:kPictureNotification object:nil];
```

// here is the action method for pictureNotification

```
-(void)pictureNotification:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSString *reason = [aNotification.userInfo objectForKey:kReasonForNotification];
    if ([reason isEqualToString:kUpdatePictureNotification])
    {
        // It was a UpdatePictureNotification
    }
    else
    {
        // It was a DeletePictureNotification
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! This is great you wrote something very understandable!